# What is the mistake in this code for generating a random password?

Tags: c#

I have written this code to generate a random password. When I run it I get an error saying that public Main() method is supposed in public class.

```
using System;

namespace Rnadom_Password_generator
{
    class Program
    {
        void Main()
        {
            string[] allCharacters = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "V", "W", "Q", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "7", "9", "0", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "=", "+", "*", "/"};
            string password = "";

            Random character = new Random();
            int passwordLength = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
            {
                int rnadomNum = character.Next(0, allCharacters.Length);
                password += allCharacters[rnadomNum];
                Console.WriteLine(password);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Make the class `public` and declare main as `public static void Main(string[] args)`

Comment: Also, don't use `Random` for passwords, it's not crypto secure.

Comment: The _real_ error you get is "Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry point". Follow those instructions to fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but reading this `public Main() method is supposed in public class` what made you think something is wrong with your code generating a random password? IMHO this message CLEARLY describes that something is declared wrong, namly that the method `Main` needs to be in a public class.

Comment: @RandRandom (and also Sean) the method and the class don't need to be public, the only modification necessary is to add static to the method. Don't even need arguments.

Comment: @gunr2171 - thought so, but I am to trustworthy that OPs at least try to give the correct error

Comment: As already mentioned, the Random class is not appropriate to generate safe passwords, because the outcome can be predicted. Instead use the cryptographically safe [RandomNumberGenerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator?view=net-6.0) class.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your main method is static. Like this.

```
using System;

namespace Rnadom_Password_generator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] allCharacters = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "U", "V", "W", "Q", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "7", "9", "0", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "=", "+", "*", "/" };
            string password = "";

            Random character = new Random();
            int passwordLength = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < passwordLength; i++)
            {
                int rnadomNum = character.Next(0, allCharacters.Length);
                password += allCharacters[rnadomNum];
                Console.WriteLine(password);
            }
        }
    }
}
```